# Is it better to check for null and return or check for non-null and continue?

Tags: null, null-check

Given the following basic class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private object m_memberVariable;

    public MyClass()
    {
       this.m_memberVariable = new object();
    }
}
```

Which of the following implementations of the `test` method is better programming practice?

```
private void test()
{
   if(this.m_memberVariable == null)
   {
       return;
   }
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(this.m_memberVariable.ToString());
}
```

Or

```
private void test()
{
   if(this.m_memberVariable != null)
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(this.m_memberVariable.ToString());
   }
}
```

In trying to recollect from a professor some 10 years ago, best practice for an if statement is to have the condition that is likely to be true more often than false (the latter). However, recently I have been using a trial of ReSharper, and their suggestion is the former. The `m_memberVariable` member is initialized at instantiation of the class and will likely be non-null for the life of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I try always to check for non-null and continue - then you have only one exit point from the function, so exit routines have to be placed in the binary code only once, which results in smaller result. But I guess that modern compilers will optimize it anyway in any case, who knows.